# How to access a port exposed from a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

```
$ docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" -a
CONTAINER ID        NAMES               PORTS
ae87d83af7d3        hopeful_engelbart   
d13e260c4dec        unruffled_bouman    
db2c482de210        jenkinsci           0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp
cd201cbd413e        xyz                 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
c64c32ac68b8        pqr
```

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                               NAMES
ae87d83af7d3        442c97a73937          "/bin/bash"              11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                                        hopeful_engelbart
d13e260c4dec        442c97a73937          "/bin/bash"              27 minutes ago      Exited (0) 24 minutes ago                                       unruffled_bouman
db2c482de210        jenkins/jenkins:lts   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   3 days ago          Up 41 minutes               0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkinsci
cd201cbd413e        442c97a73937          "bash"                   3 days ago          Up 7 minutes                0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp        xyz
c64c32ac68b8        442c97a73937          "bash"                   3 days ago          Exited (0) 2 days ago                                           pqr
```

Above outputs show that the port 5000 has been exposed (I  hope).

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' xyz
172.17.0.3
```

Now when I do from the host machine:

```
wget -c 172.17.0.3:5000
--2019-12-30 16:26:44--  http://172.17.0.3:5000/
Connecting to 172.17.0.3:5000... failed: Connection refused.
```

What is the way to access that port since it is exposed and the container is running?

```
$ wget -c localhost:5000
--2019-12-30 16:41:57--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2019-12-30 16:41:58--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:5000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Comment: What about `wget -c 127.0.0.1:5000` ?

Comment: please  see the edit. @KamilCuk

Comment: So it works, you connected. And?

Comment: From what you've shown, the `xyz` container isn't running a server, it's running `bash`, so network connections to it will fail regardless of whether or not you have a port exposed.  If it's running something other than an interactive shell, you need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that.  Unless you're on one very specific Docker/host OS configuration the `docker inspect` IP address is unusable and you shouldn't look it up.

Comment: @KamilCuk it is showing read error. What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidMaze ` the xyz container isn't running a server, it's running bash` This is true. Am I supposed to run it as a server? What is the way to do that?

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Yes it's read error - there is nothing to read, did you expect that some data (what data?) would be available to read from port 5000?

Comment: @kamilcuk well, I am running an application inside the container which displays something on port 5000. I expect wget to get something from that webpage. Please tell how to achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check if you have an application, listening to the port inside your container. Just try to connect to it from your container:

```
docker exec xyz wget 127.0.0.1:5000
```

If it'll work then you have a problem with port exposing, otherwise, there is no web server running inside your container.

And the error you get

```
Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
```

seems to point to the problem in your web server rather then connectivity issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Am I supposed to manually run the webserver inside the container?

Comment: If you run it using `docker run`, you should run it manually, or it is written CMD in Dockerfile. And if you use docker-compose, it usually written in `docker-compose.yaml`. Check the docs of image developers is should be some information about it. Or if it's your image, Add ENTRYPOINT or CMD into Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem running one Quarkus application with Docker.

I found [this topic on forum.dockers](https://forums.docker.com/t/hapijs-application-not-responses-correctly-http-request-sent-awaiting-response-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer-in-headers/58097) talking about a similar issue.

In this topic is said:

> I was using flask, by default it binds to localhost & 5000, so you have to specify:
> app.run(host=“0.0.0.0”)

So, in my case I guess the problem was on my application and not on Docker network.

I added this property on the Java command to start my application on my Dockerfile and everything worked fine:

```
-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0
```